# having a problem setting my a page as a homepage on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently getting this error while loading up the homepage. I have only create the first page which I's trying to make the homepage. *TweeetsController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html* Below are my codes for the controller, view, and routes. Thank you for any help.

Controller:

```
class TweeetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tweeet, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tweeets
  # GET /tweeets.json
  def index
    @tweeets = Tweeet.all
  end

  # GET /tweeets/1
  # GET /tweeets/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tweeets/new
  def new
    @tweeet = Tweeet.new
  end

  # GET /tweeets/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tweeets
  # POST /tweeets.json
  def create
    @tweeet = Tweeet.new(tweeet_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tweeet.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tweeet, notice: 'Tweeet was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tweeet }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tweeet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tweeets/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tweeets/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tweeet.update(tweeet_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tweeet, notice: 'Tweeet was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tweeet }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tweeet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tweeets/1
  # DELETE /tweeets/1.json
  def destroy
    @tweeet.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tweeets_url, notice: 'Tweeet was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_tweeet
      @tweeet = Tweeet.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def tweeet_params
      params.require(:tweeet).permit(:tweeet)
    end
end
```

view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Tweeets</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tweeet</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @tweeets.each do |tweeet| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= tweeet.tweeet %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', tweeet %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tweeet_path(tweeet) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', tweeet, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Tweeet', new_tweeet_path %>
```

routes:

```
  resources :tweeets
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  root "tweeets#index"

end
```

model:

```
class Tweeet < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: what is the view file name and path?

Comment: **app\views\tweeets\index.html.erb** is the path and file name

Comment: does that work if you request "/tweeets"?

Comment: I got it to render and show up as expected with the windows cmd. It gave me that error while using git bash. Any ideas why? Read that it could possibly be puma? But that was installed from the beginning. Maybe yarn got? I would like to run everything on git bash if possible

Comment: how do you use git bash to execute that?